# Using require to set templateUrl in Angular 2 while getting error

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

in my component, I want to set templateUrl using require, like this:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';


@Component({
    selector: 'header',
    styleUrls: ['app/header/header.css'],
    templateUrl: require('./hahaha.html')
})
export class HeaderComponent {

  logoUrl: string = '/resources/img/branding.png';


  constructor () {

  }

}
```

In my console, I got an error

> angular2-polyfills.js:332 Error: TypeError: require is not a function
>         at eval (http://localhost:3000/app/header/header.js:29:35)
>         at execute (http://localhost:3000/app/header/header.js:34:14)   Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.js

I want to be able to do something like this: (I do know a work around, but I just want to know more, how to make this works in other way)

```
// Note that this is a relative path, which I will get error for now, I have to write from root path, don't like it.
styleUrls: ['./header.css']  
templateUrl: require('./hahaha.html')
```

This is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to use require? just use the path?

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz I want to know how can make require work, though I do know a work around, I just curious.

Comment: What do you expect the difference to be between `templateUrl: require('./hahaha.html')` and just plain `templateUrl: 'hahaha.html'`?

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz I do not expect any difference, I simply want to know why the require won't work in this case, cause I thought it should work.

Comment: Well `require` is a part of CommonJS, you'd need to have a module loader that speaks CommonJS. But you're already using the `import from` syntax in your other code. You can't have it bothways.

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz So, if I change the module: "commonjs" , it will work?

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz  How can I use relative path then...

Comment: No keep it as system :) just make a relative path from your root document. :) Usually your index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `require('./hahaha.html')` will be the template string, but `templateUrl` field expects the *PATH* to the .html template.

**Solution 1**: use `template` field if you want to proceed with `require` function

**Example:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'header',
  styleUrls: ['app/header/header.css'],
  template: require('./hahaha.html')
})
```

**Solution 2**: use `templateUrl` but in this case, you have to path to the .html template

**Example:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'header',
  styleUrls: ['app/header/header.css'],
  templateUrl: './hahaha.html'
})
```

**Update:** in case with `templateUrl` - template load should be asynchronous(AMD), but with `template` - template will be inlined into javascript

Comment: In Solution 1 you say template but you put templateUrl

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `require` just use a relative path from the root of your document.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'header',
    styleUrls: ['app/header/header.css'],
    templateUrl: 'app/header/hahaha.html'
})
```

Comment: Why I can't write this: styleUrls: ['./header.css'], the header.ts file is in the same fold of header.css

Comment: Because your module loader loads all your js code into one location. :)