# Angular 2 Typescript : How to export external JS variable

Tags: typescript, angular, export

I have a Configuration JS file where some config variables are there.
For ex :

```
var config = {url:"xyz.com"};
```

I want to access this config parameters through out my application.

As export is the right way to export anything i Tried 
    export var appConfig = config

but its giving error saying can not get property url of undefined.

Answer (score 4):

1. First you will have to allowJs to true in the tsconfig.json compiler options:

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,

2. And then,

create a javascript file within the app folder. You can create the javascript file in any folder or any component. For example app/javascriptTest.js

3. In app/javascriptTest.js for example you want to export a variable, A, In the blank app/javascriptTest.js file you type:

export var A = 2;

4. You go to the typescript file you want to import the variable A to, for example in app/componentName/header.ts
   you import at the top with:

import { A } from "../javascriptTest.js"

5. Finally within app/componentName/header.ts typescript file you can use the A variable as it is.

let x="Hello "+A;

I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide it using Angulars DI using a string key (or `OpaqueToken`) and request it by `@Inject('keyName')`:

```
var config = {url:"xyz.com"};

bootstrap(AppComponent, [provide('myConfig', {useValue: config})]);
```

```
export class SomeComponent { // or SomeService
  constructor(@Inject('myConfig') private config) {}
}
```

Comment: Actually the config variable is going to get used outside the class.
For ex :
@Component({
    selector: 'app-page',
    templateUrl: "ui/"+envConfig.platform+".html"
})

Comment: Then you are probably looking for something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434546/using-require-to-set-templateurl-in-angular-2-while-getting-error

Comment: No, this is Fine, what my issue is the Path which needs to get required in the templateURI is dynamic which will come from the config variable
for Ex : 
@Component({ selector: 'app-page', templateUrl: "ui/"+config.platform+".html" })

Comment: I guess you can create property on `window` and load from there. Before bootstrap `window.myConfig = {url:"xyz.com"};` and then use it like `window.myConfig.url`

Comment: Yes I am using it like this right now and It works fine, but the issue is it shows error or tslint so is not a valid code, there must be a way to do so.
I tried below stuffs but not working.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27417107/how-use-an-external-non-typescript-library-from-typescript-without-d-ts

Comment: tslint just doesn't know about `window.xxx` that doesn't mean it's invalid. You can make it known but I don't use TS/JS (only Dart) and don't know about these details.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your time to write , I will keep trying some other ways

Answer (score 0):

> I want to access this config parameters through out my application.

Just export `config.ts`:

```
export const config = {url:"xyz.com"};
```

And then import as needed:

```
import {config} from "./path/to/config";
```

And yes. No `.ts` at the end.